# Exporting a pandas df to sqlite leads to duplicate datasets instead of one updated dataset

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy, dataset

I'm uploading a pandas dataframe from a csv file into a sqlite database via sqlalchmemy.
The initial filling is working just fine, but when I rerun the following code, the same data is exported again and the database contains two identical datasets.

How can I change the code, so that only new or changed data is uploaded into the database?

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Set up of the engine to connect to the database
# the urlquote is used for passing the password which might contain special characters such as "/"
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///historical_data3.db')
conn = engine.connect()
Base = declarative_base()

# Declaration of the class in order to write into the database. This structure is standard and should align with SQLAlchemy's doc.
class Timeseries_Values(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Timeseries_Values'

    #id = Column(Integer)
    Date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    ProductID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Value = Column(Numeric)

    @property
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(Date='%s', ProductID='%s', Value='%s')" % (self.Date, self.ProductID, self.Value)



fileToRead = r'V:\PYTHON\ProjectDatabase\HistoricalDATA_V13.csv'
tableToWriteTo = 'Timeseries_Values'

# Panda to create a dataframe with ; as separator.
df = pd.read_csv(fileToRead, sep=';', decimal=',', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)
# The orient='records' is the key of this, it allows to align with the format mentioned in the doc to insert in bulks.
listToWrite = df.to_dict(orient='records')

# Set up of the engine to connect to the database
# the urlquote is used for passing the password which might contain special characters such as "/"

metadata = sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True)
table = sqlalchemy.Table(tableToWriteTo, metadata, autoload=True)

# Open the session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Insert the dataframe into the database in one bulk
conn.execute(table.insert(), listToWrite)

# Commit the changes
session.commit()

# Close the session
session.close()
```

Comment: Have you created the table using your Declarative model? It shouldn't allow duplicates to begin with if so, since *{  Date, ProductID }* is a key.

Comment: Are you saying that the issue is about how I have set up the database in the first place and not about the "export code"?

Comment: Both. If your table had a primary key as described in your Declarative model, it would not allow inserting rows with duplicate values in the key columns. The export code must take in to account the fact that there may be duplicates and decide what to do about those.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining this. So I have set up the table once again, using the declarative model. The initial export works fine and when I try to export the same data again to the table, I get an "sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed". So that makes sense, but when I try to export a new dataset that contains both new and old data, I get the same error. Do I have to change the "conn.execute(table.insert(), listToWrite)" code? I've tried update() instead of insert(), but that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is working now, I 've added the df.to_sql code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Set up of the engine to connect to the database
# the urlquote is used for passing the password which might contain special characters such as "/"
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///historical_data3.db')
conn = engine.connect()
Base = declarative_base()

# Declaration of the class in order to write into the database. This structure is standard and should align with SQLAlchemy's doc.
class Timeseries_Values(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Timeseries_Values'

    #id = Column(Integer)
    Date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    ProductID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Value = Column(Numeric)


fileToRead = r'V:\PYTHON\ProjectDatabase\HistoricalDATA_V13.csv'
tableToWriteTo = 'Timeseries_Values'

# Panda to create a dataframe with ; as separator.
df = pd.read_csv(fileToRead, sep=';', decimal=',', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)
# The orient='records' is the key of this, it allows to align with the format mentioned in the doc to insert in bulks.
listToWrite = df.to_dict(orient='records')

df.to_sql(name='Timeseries_Values', con=conn, if_exists='replace')

metadata = sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True)
table = sqlalchemy.Table(tableToWriteTo, metadata, autoload=True)

# Open the session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Insert the dataframe into the database in one bulk
conn.execute(table.insert(), listToWrite)

# Commit the changes
session.commit()

# Close the session
session.close()
```